# How do I convert the background of Edit Control to transparent in mFC VC++?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

[Output is show in picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Azb3a.png)

> I am using one CStatic control with variable as "m_background" and ID as IDC_background. In this control, the video has been run on the click of the button. and there is second control Edit Control with variable as "m_edit" and ID as IDC_edit.This Edit Box is placed over static control. I want to show the text written in Edit Control on video while we play video on click of the button with transparent background color of EDit Control.
>   But the problem is grey/white background has appeared for m_edit control while we play video. I want to show the text on the video with transparent background of the "m_edit" control while we play the video.

```c
BOOL CtestcodeDlg::OnInitDialog()//To set up the video in background and text above the video
{
    m_background.ModifyStyle(0, WS_CLIPSIBLINGS);   
    m_edit.SetWindowPos(&CWnd::wndTop, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
         SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOACTIVATE|WS_EX_TRANSPARENT);
    return TRUE;  // return TRUE  unless you set the focus to a control
}

HBRUSH CtestcodeDlg::OnCtlColor(CDC* pDC, CWnd* pWnd, UINT nCtlColor) //To transparent the background of Edit box
{
    HBRUSH hbr = CDialogEx::OnCtlColor(pDC, pWnd, nCtlColor);
    HBRUSH m_default=CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0,0, 0));
    if(pWnd->GetDlgCtrlID() == IDC_edit)
    {
        pDC->SetTextColor(RGB(255,0,0));
        pDC->SetBkColor(TRANSPARENT);
        pDC->SetBkMode(TRANSPARENT);
    }
    return hbr;
}

void CtestcodeDlg::OnBnClickedButton1()////To run the video
{
    my_instance = libvlc_new(0, NULL);
    my_media_file = libvlc_media_new_location(my_instance, 
                               "rtsp://BigBuckBunny_115k.mov");
    my_player = libvlc_media_player_new_from_media(my_media_file);
    my_event_manager = libvlc_media_player_event_manager(my_player);
    libvlc_media_player_play(my_player);
    libvlc_audio_set_track(my_player ,-1);
    libvlc_media_player_set_hwnd(my_player, m_background);
    Sleep(1000); 
    _beginthread(test, 0, NULL);
    libvlc_audio_set_track(my_player ,-1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [SetLayeredWindowAttributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setlayeredwindowattributes) function, with the crKey of your bk color.
Also, i think `pDC->SetBkColor(TRANSPARENT);` in your code is a mistake, it sets bk color to black. Try to run without this call.

Comment: I run the program without this call but     
       pDC->SetBkColor(TRANSPARENT); but this is not working.